# Flutter passing Firestore UID into repository

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

For my project, I am using firestore to get the data per user. Therefore I created the following structure in Firestore.

The data is stored in:
Collection: users > Document: UID (variable) > Collection: reminders

In order to get the data from Firestore I need to pass the UID into the repository. My reminder repository doesn't have this data standard therefor I get it via a call to Firebase.

Let me show the code to make it more clear:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

import 'package:diabetes/src/model/models.dart';
import 'package:diabetes/src/entities/entities.dart';
import 'package:diabetes/src/repositories/repositories.dart';

class FirebaseRemindersRepository implements RemindersRepository {
  final reminderCollection = Firestore.instance.collection("users");

  @override
  Future<void> addNewReminder(Reminder reminder) async {
    try {
      final user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
      final uid = user.uid;
      return reminderCollection
          .document(uid)
          .collection("reminders")
          .add(reminder.toEntity().toDocument());
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> deleteReminder(Reminder reminder) async {
    try {
      final user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
      final uid = user.uid;
      return reminderCollection
          .document(uid)
          .collection("reminders")
          .document(reminder.id)
          .delete();
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }

  @override
  Stream<List<Reminder>> reminders() {
    return reminderCollection.snapshots().map((snapshot) {
      return snapshot.documents
          .map((doc) => Reminder.fromEntity(ReminderEntity.fromSnapshot(doc)))
          .toList();
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<void> updateReminder(Reminder update) async {
    try {
      final user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
      final uid = user.uid;
      return reminderCollection
          .document(uid)
          .collection("reminders")
          .document(update.id)
          .updateData(update.toEntity().toDocument());
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see this makes me repeat this part a lot:

```
final user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
final uid = user.uid;
```

Also, I am not able to do the same here:

```
Stream<List<Reminder>> reminders() {
```